# Передать значение из одной функции в другую функцию?

Tags: c++

Как из функции `add_matrix_A` и `add_matrix_B` предать `N и M` в функцию `matrix_C`?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void menu() {
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Что вы хотите сделать?\n";
    cout << "1. Ввести матрицу A\n";
    cout << "2. Ввести матрицу B\n";
    cout << "3. Вычислить матрицу C=A*B и транспонировать\n";
    cout << "4. Умножить матрицу A на k\n";
    cout << "5. Умножить на матрицу B на транспонированную C\n";
    cout << "6. Выполнить операцию k*A+B*CT\n";
    cout << "7. Выход\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << ">>> ";
}

void add_matrix_A() {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Ввод матрицы A:" << endl << endl;
    int i, j, N, M, a[20][20];
    cout << "Количество строк: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Количество столбцов: ";
    cin >> M;
    cout << "\nВведите матрицу A:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nМатрица A:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void add_matrix_B() {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Ввод матрицы B:" << endl << endl;
    int i, j, N, M, b[20][20];
    cout << "Количество строк: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Количество столбцов: ";
    cin >> M;
    cout << "\nВведите матрицу B:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cin >> b[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nМатрица B:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cout << b[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void matrix_C() {
    system("cls");
    int a[20][20], b[20][20];
    cout << "Вычисление матрицы C=A*B" << endl << endl;
    int i, j, k, c[20][20];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
        cout << "\nМатрица C:" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int variant, N, M;
    do
    {
        menu();
        cin >> variant;
        switch (variant)
        {
        case 1:
            add_matrix_A();
            break;
        case 2:
            add_matrix_B();
            break;
        case 3:
            matrix_C();
        }
        if (variant != 7) {
            system("pause");
        }
    } while (variant !=7);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::pair<int, int> add_matrix_B() {    
    //...
    int N, M;
    cin >> N >> M;
    //...
    return std::make_pair(N, M);
}

void matrix_C(const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    //...
    int n = p.first, m = p.second;
    //...
}
```

можете передать и так:

```
matrix_C(add_matrix_B());
```

Comment: а как-то можно без `pair`?

Comment: можно конечно  но во что то всерано придется хранить. Можете написать структуру, использовать стандартные структуры и классы, и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

сделай А и Б возвращающими int[] и потом передай их в C 
по типу :

```
return {N,M};
```

main потом запиши так:

```
int a[] = add_matrix_A();
int b[] = add_matrix_B();
matrix_C(a[0],a[1], b[0],b[1]);
```

а matrix_C переделай :

```
void matrix_C(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
system("cls");
int a[a][b], b[c][d];
cout << "Вычисление матрицы C=A*B" << endl << endl;
int i, j, k, c[20][20];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        c[i][j] = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
    cout << "\nМатрица C:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то не работает :(

Comment: я бы порекомедовал возвращать пару, а не массив

Comment: @slvk.m а вы хоть поменяли возвращаемое значение в `add_matix_A` & `add_matrix_B`?

Comment: @Yerassyl да, я поменял

Comment: какой ответ ошибки? какой Exception показывает?

Comment: @slvk.m на какое возвращаемое знач поменяли ?

Comment: @Yerassyl Maikhanov я скорее всего что-то не правильно сделал, я новичок в c++ :(

Comment: @Yerassyl Maikhanov я изменил `void add_matrix_A` на `int add_matrix_A` и в конце функции добавил `return { N,M }` и дальше по вашему ответу делал

Comment: @slvk.m я раньше начинал с++ но потом устал от нагромождений и контроля памяти и перешел на Java)

Comment: @slvk.m int[] add_matrix, можешь еще на них ссылкой ссылаться не создавая доп. переменных по типу *a = add_matrix_A()

Comment: @Yerassyl Maikhanov упс, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Yerassyl Maikhanov 24 ошибки вышло :(

Comment: @YerassylMaikhanov ссылкой? Ты имеешь ввиду возвращать ссылку из функции?

Comment: [возвращение массива из функции](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function)